# Can't remove a hidden bootcamp partition

Tags: macos, bootcamp, partition, disk-space

I had a bootcamp partition that I'd wanted to remove. It seemed like it'd been removed using bootcamp, but it is still taking up a big chunk of space in the System storage, and now I can't find it to get rid of it. This is what the `diskutil list` returns:

```
Last login: Fri Jan 17 13:03:32 on ttys000
Elisas-MacBook-Pro-2:~ Elisa$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         199.0 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +199.0 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            138.5 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 24.5 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                519.0 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk1s4
```

I have looked through other threads on this topic but haven't found a solution to work, as I don't have the extra disks for bootcamp that other posts have shown. Any help is appreciated, this is really not one of my skill areas.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk0s2 0`?

Comment: @DavidAnderson That appears to have fixed it, thank you so much!